# Avoiding overlapping of paint events, arching lines through click and drag?

Tags: visual-c++, graphics, gdi

I am currently a student and trying to design a Visual C++ application to allow me to visually insert an oriented graph in order to create a text file with the graph's matrix. At this point I have created an onClick event to create nodes and have used the form's Paint  event to draw the nodes. I have also inserted the conditions to avoid nodes from overlapping.

I am currently working on creating the links between nodes. The problem that I have encountered is that the line that unites two nodes crosses another node. I consider that writing an algorithm to detect overlapping and calculate how much the line needs to arch in order to avoid that is too tedious in this situation.

Therefore I thought about creating a line that can be arched by the user by clicking and dragging it to the left or right, however I have had problems finding any tutorials on how to do this. So if anyone has ever had to introduce this kind of arching line in a project or has any idea where I could find some information about this I would deeply appreciate it.

Mentions:

1. please do not recommend any fancy graphics libraries for doing this, as I am not interested in installing 3rd party stuff for this program. The function I want to insert the code into is named something like form1_onPaint, so I would like to keep it strictly to the C++ standard libraries.
2. I know I said I am interested in arching a line through click and drag, however if someone could suggest another viable solution to this, such as a function that detects overlapping in onPaint events or anything else that could be of use to solve this it would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to allow the user to grab and drag the midpoint of one of the connector lines, which would break the line into two segments (joined at the ends). That keeps things simple and avoids the need to deal with complex curves, and it would be pretty simple to implement. You could get fancy and allow additional subdividing of lines, so a single line could eventually be broken into any number of sub-lines.

Some basic ideas on what would be required to do this:

- A representation of the line segments and the various points defining the ends. You might store one point for one end, one point for each of the intermediate segment break points, and a final point for the other end.
- A way to track where the cursor is, so that when it's close to the midpoint of a line you can prepare to grab and drag the line to split it. The "mouse move" event will play a role in this. Not sure which toolkit you're using, or I would be more specific about what the event would be named - it might be onMouseMove.
- A way to track drag operations. This will probably involve "mouse down", "mouse move", and "mouse up". As you drag, you'd be updating the coordinates of the relevant segment break point.

Unfortunately I think the basic drawing/windowing system isn't going to be of much use in trying to detect paints that overlap each other. You can do it yourself, but I agree with your thought that it may be tricky and tedious to code.

The final product might look something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [misterfoo.com](http://www.misterfoo.com/data/link-demo.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw curves, then look at the Windows GDI function `PolyBezier()`.

Create an array of four points: The first and last points should be the endpoints, i.e. the nodes you are connecting two and from.  The two middle points should both be the same, and should be the 'point' of the curve, i.e. the position you are dragging with the mouse.

Comment: Good to know, I've never used that one before. The winforms version of this, if the questioner is using forms, is Graphics.DrawBezier.